# prestashop view invoice page is throwing error

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am facing problem in Prestashop invoive view. When i am trying to view invoice it throw an error.

```
PHP Warning:  include(D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\eduworldsolution.com\womenbuity.com/translations/en/pdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\eduworldsolution.com\womenbuity.com\classes\Translate.php on line 237
```

I check the Translation directory and there is no existing "en/pdf.php" file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should download the default Prestashop installation of your version and just copy this file `pdf.php` from there.

Comment: Thanks Indre. Please tell me where i will find the pdf.php. I means path for that file in the installation package.

Comment: Path is the same, check in your Prestashop folder `translations/en/pdf.php`.